# How to add style to Listbox Items using Blend

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-8, expression-blend

I have a List box code in the XAML, below is my code:

```
<!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="2" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ListBox Name="listBox" 
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                     VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                     SelectionChanged="TopicListboxSelectionChanged"
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,10" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Border Background="Gray">
                                    <TextBlock Height="50" 
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Text="{Binding Path=Value}"></TextBlock>
                                </Border>
                            </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>              
        </Grid>
```

Now i need to add style to list box item, like the below image, along with onclick effect.

How to do it using Blend ? so that if i need to add styles to any other item tomorrow i can add it myself whithout seeking any help.

If there are any tutorials avaiable to learn, please provide me a link on that.

Comment: what kind of effect you want on onclick?

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal first thing i need to learn how to apply atyle using blend, when clicked it should indicate the user with any color that he has selected that option.

Comment: you need to learn the visual states of any control(pressed, released, focused etc etc), and the parent you are taking in your datatemplate is a stackpanel, and stack panel has no such visual states. I would better suggest you to take a button instead.

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal ok you mean StackPanel add Button there ?

Comment: Nopes, Remove everyting from the datatemplate,and add a button, and bind the content of it to Content="{Binding Path=Value}". This would make multiple buttons and also exhibit an onclick effect, And regarding the style.. I will update it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a style in a Page

Below all the namespace declaration in your page

Just make a tag

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

and declare the below style in it

```
        <Style x:Key="style_ColorButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,10,5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black">

                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Gray"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Using this style with a button.

```
<Button Height="40" Width="40" Name="btnAcceptCrop" Click="btnAcceptCrop_Click" Style="{StaticResource style_ColorButton}"/>
```

Comment: ok will check this once, but how did you do it ?, i need to learn

Comment: thats easy, just an easy link to take a start with http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/windows-phone-button-default-style

Comment: how to add list box ItemContainerStyle ?

Comment: that is used when you don't want to define a datatemplate inside the listbox, Check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.itemcontainerstyle(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: So using button is better approach ?

Comment: yes if you want to show different colors on different visual states, also button is programmed that way to change color when its pressed, released etc.

Comment: Its working fine now, thanks for your help, but i have some issues here, like 1) how to i know which item iscliked and its value ? 2) since i am working on multiple selection of list items i need to highlight the list item how to acheive this ? can you please help me ?

Comment: please have a look at here, which is what i am exactly looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911120/how-to-highlight-selected-item-in-list-box-windows-phone?rq=1

Comment: OKAY, I will update you with some solutions very soon.